# Remove path from filename

Tags: go

I have trivial question.

I have string which contains a filename and it's path. How can i remove whole path? I have tried those:

```
line = "/some/path/to/remove/file.name"
line := strings.LastIndex(line, "/")
fmt.Println(line)
```

It prints some strange number:

```
38
```

I need it without last slash

Thanks a lot

Comment: The "strange number" is the location of the Last "/" in the string. LastIndex returns the *index" in the string of the last occurence of the requested substring.

Answer (score 139):

The number is the index of the last slash in the string. If you want to get the file's base name, use [`filepath.Base`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Base):

```
path := "/some/path/to/remove/file.name"
file := filepath.Base(path)
fmt.Println(file)
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/DzlCV-HC-r.

Comment: Excellent thanks. Just found it :) Was going to post it here but you were quicker :)

Comment: Found this doesn't work if your Go server is on Linux and your browser is Edge on Windows. It won't strip Windows paths when the server is on Linux :(

Answer (score 28):

**You can try it in the [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/G0kJUazYNH9)!**

```
dir, file := filepath.Split("/some/path/to/remove/file.name")
fmt.Println("Dir:", dir)   //Dir: /some/path/to/remove/
fmt.Println("File:", file) //File: file.name
```

Comment: Playground: [https://play.golang.org/p/uUthOtpkSAz](https://play.golang.org/p/uUthOtpkSAz)

Comment: This is actually a proper answer as filepath.Base("/") will give you "/" (root path) and filepath.Base("") will give you "." so current directory. Returned file in filepath.Split() for both cases will be empty string.

Comment: This also fails if your browser is on a different OS than your server. If the browser sends Windows directory and your server is on Linux this fails. :(

Answer (score 10):

Another option:

```
package main
import "path"

func main() {
   line := "/some/path/to/remove/file.name"
   line = path.Base(line)
   println(line == "file.name")
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/path#Base

Comment: Maybe you could point out if there is an advantage over the accepted solution...

Answer (score 3):

If you want the base path without the fileName, you can use Dir, which is documented here: https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Dir

Quoting part of their documentation:

> Dir returns all but the last element of path, typically the path's directory. After dropping the final element, Dir calls Clean on the path and trailing slashes are removed.

Also from their documentation, running this code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "path/filepath"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("On Unix:")
    fmt.Println(filepath.Dir("/foo/bar/baz.js"))
    fmt.Println(filepath.Dir("/foo/bar/baz"))
    fmt.Println(filepath.Dir("/foo/bar/baz/"))
    fmt.Println(filepath.Dir("/dirty//path///"))
    fmt.Println(filepath.Dir("dev.txt"))
    fmt.Println(filepath.Dir("../todo.txt"))
    fmt.Println(filepath.Dir(".."))
    fmt.Println(filepath.Dir("."))
    fmt.Println(filepath.Dir("/"))
    fmt.Println(filepath.Dir(""))

}
```

will give you this output:

On Unix:

```
 /foo/bar
 /foo/bar
 /foo/bar/baz
 /dirty/path
 .
 ..
 .
 .
 /
 .
```

Try it yourself here:

https://play.golang.org/p/huk3EmORFw5

If you instead want to get the fileName without the base path, @Ainar-G has sufficiently answered that.