# remove the last folder from a path

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var loc = window.location.pathname;
var dir = loc.substring(0, loc.lastIndexOf('/'));
```

loc returns as:

```
/public/html/signup/
```

dir returns as:

```
/public/html/signup
```

I want to remove the name of the folder too so i get back:

```
/public/html/
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: How about you execute the same `x.substring(0, x.lastIndexOf('/'));` on the resulting dir string?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove path from filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34527672/remove-path-from-filename)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you go. It's a universal solution so that you can strip as many folders as you want to - just pass something else than 1.

```
var path = window.location.pathname.split("/");
var strippedPath = path.slice(0, path.length-1).join("/");
```

Comment: in this case, he need `length - 2` since the string ends with `/`.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one javascript native method that I know that remove an array element and return a deep copy of this modified list. I could mention also `reduce` but this is out the scope here.

`const new_path = path.split('/').filter((basename, index, array) => index !== array.length - (basename === '' ? 2 : 1)).join('/');`

Filter is cool since it helps us to sort out basenames that are empties in a callback, equivalent to a spitted trailing slash within the path in our case.